# How to trigger an event declared in a dll file in a c# application

Tags: c#, .net, dll

I'm curently working as an intern in a SAP business partner company. Here my main task is to develop AddOns to SAP B1. I already built an AddOn in c#. Now my boss wants me to create an update function to this AddOn and register this under SAP B1. And afterwards whenever I create a new function the AddOn should be able to download this function automatically and then the user will be able to use this new function too.

My first step was to write my own updater function which checks for updates during the start up and if there's an update(ex: on the FTP server) download the new "exe" file and replace the old one after making a back up file. But this is not possible due to the fact that it changes the checksum which makes it not runnable in SAP anymore.

So my only option is to include all these functions in a dll file(according to my research) and attach it to the application. So whenever there's a new function I can replace the old dll with the new one. But my problem is how to trigger these functions,events.. which are defiend in the dll in the application.

```
    Cplus_Function_Library.Class1  obj = new Cplus_Function_Library.Class1();
```

Becauese when I try to create an object from the library like this inside the application it gives this error:

**An exception(first chance) of the type "System.ArgumentNullException" has occurred in System.Core.dll
Additional information: Value cannot be null. If a handler is available for this exception, the program may continue to run safely.**

If someone can give me a suggestion how to do it with some examples it would really help me. But please understand that I'm just an intern who's not that great in progamming. So don't give me really complicated answer which I won't be able to follow. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was I had to include the connection function which connects my application to the SAP inside the DTOR in dll file. And then everything works smoothly.